# jstl token split function

Tags: split, jstl, tokenize

I am trying to split a string(variable name is colorString) like below..

```
 '7000000000000003601/_/SHP_COLOR/_/Color/_/3.00000/_/7000000000006065548/_/DragonBerry/_/DragonBerry/_/49.00000/_/1/_/0/_/0/_/0/_/0/_/1/_/DragonBerry_Small.jpg'
```

I am splitting it by string '/_/'
All i need is last element 'DragonBerry_Small.jpg'
i am only getting Small.jpg

here is the code snippet

```
<c:set var="splitURI" value="${fn:split(colorString, '\\\/_\\\/')}"/>
<c:set var="imgName" value="${splitURI[fn:length(splitURI)-1]}"/>
```

What am i doing here..Please help.

I am facing the same issue when there is a space like 'DragonBerry Small.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fn:split splits based on individual characters not strings.   So the trick is to do a substitution where you substitute the string for a character that won't show up in the string (typically a pipe works well).

Example:

```
<c:set var="colorStringTransformed" value="${fn:replace(colorString, '/_/', '|')}"/>
```

Now the colorStringTransformed should look like:

```
'700000000000000360|SHP_COLOR|Color|3.00000|7000000000006065548|DragonBerry|DragonBerry|49.00000|1|0|0|0|0|1|DragonBerry_Small.jpg'
```

And then you can split it.

```
<c:set var="splitURI" value="${fn:split(colorStringTransformed, '|')}"/>
<c:set var="imgName" value="${splitURI[fn:length(splitURI)-1]}"/>
```